# Show featured image in sidebar

Tags: post-thumbnails, sidebar

I'm adding a widget on my sidebar but the Featured Image isn't shown.

this is the code of my side bar:

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the main widget areas.
 *
 * @package PowerMag
 * @since PowerMag 1.0
 */
?>
    <div id="sidebar" <?php if ( of_get_option('pm_sidebar_position') == 'sidebar-content' ) { echo 'class="span4"'; } ?> >




        <div id="secondary" role="complementary">

        <?php do_action( 'before_sidebar' ); ?>         

        <?php 

                //Select wich sidebar will be display
                $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'sidebar-1'; //Default Sidebar

                //If is page or single.
                if(is_singular()){

                    global $wp_query;
                    $post = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
                    $selected_sidebar_replacement = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'sbg_selected_sidebar_replacement', true);

                    //If default selected
                    if($selected_sidebar_replacement == '0' || $selected_sidebar_replacement == ''){
                        $selected_sidebar_replacement = 'sidebar-1';
                    }

                    // Reset the global $the_post as this query will have stomped on it
                    wp_reset_query();

                }       

                if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement)) : else : ?>

            <p>You selected an empty sidebar, try populating it with some awesome widgets!</p>

            <?php endif; // end sidebar widget area ?>
        </div><!-- #secondary -->
    </div><!-- #sidebar -->
```

Comment: What is it exactly what you want? A Featured Image in a Widget? Why do you post your sidebar code then and not the code of the Widget?

Comment: yes its a widgets

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Post Thumbnail by [`get_the_post_thumbnail( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail).
Inside your widget add the following code:

```
global $post;

if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
  echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'your-image-size' );
```

If there is a Featured Image, it will be shown.

Comment: in side the widget code where i put this code?

Comment: See the [Widget API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API), you have to paste this code in the `public function widget`.

Answer (score 1):

You can put your code wherever you want to show the sidebar like on header or on left or right based on your theme file.

```
if ( function_exists( 'dynamic_sidebar' ) && dynamic_sidebar( $selected_sidebar_replacement) ) { 
     /*code to display featured image here*/
     global $post;

     if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) )
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID, 'your-image-size' );
     } else {
     /*else do this*/
     }
} else {
    /*else do this*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions to display the sidebar might be met, but there is no command to display the sidebar:

```
if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement)) : else : ?>
```

You should have

```
if (function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') && dynamic_sidebar($selected_sidebar_replacement)) { 
*code to display featured image here*
} else {
*else do this*
} ?>
```

Comment: the post is display but no thumbnail image is display

Comment: *code to display featured image here* from where to i put this code